# Workbox. Why my Cache Storage is empty? What I did wrong?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, workbox

I started to use the Workbox for Service Workers. 
But my Cache Storage in DevTools is empty.
What I did wrong?

Here is code of my service-workers.js file:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js');
if (workbox) {
console.log("Yay! Workbox is loaded ");
    const {registerRoute} = workbox.routing;
    const {CacheFirst} = workbox.strategies;
    const {ExpirationPlugin} = workbox.expiration;
    registerRoute(
// Cache image files
        /.*\.(?:js|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|mp4|webp)/,
        // Use the cache if it's available
        new CacheFirst({
            // Use a custom cache name
            cacheName: 'images-cache',
            cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [0, 200], // Make sure 0 is included in this list.
            }
        })
    );


} else {
    console.log("Boo! Workbox didn't load ");
}
```